# How to customise ModelAdmin UI

Tags: django, wagtail

How does one go about editing the template(s) shown when using `wagtail.contrib.modeladmin`?

Assuming

```py
class EventsAdmin(ModelAdmin):

    menu_label = 'Events'
    list_display = ('title',)
```

**Say I want to make the titles clickable, how would I go about doing so?**

I figured I could check the templates in `wagtail/contrib/modeladmin/templates` and add something like `<a href="{{ url }}" />` alas the furthest I got to finding that title section was in `wagtail/contrib/modeladmin/templates/modeladmin/includes/result_row_value.html` where it outputs the title section through the `{{ item }}` tag

```html
{% load i18n modeladmin_tags %}
{{ item }}{{ url }}{% if add_action_buttons %}
    {% if action_buttons %}
    <ul class="actions">
        {% for button in action_buttons %}
            <li>{% include 'modeladmin/includes/button.html' %}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% endif %}
    {{ closing_tag }}
{% endif %}
```

```py
#modeladmin_tags.py

@register.inclusion_tag(
    "modeladmin/includes/result_row_value.html", takes_context=True)
def result_row_value_display(context, index):
    add_action_buttons = False
    item = context['item']
    closing_tag = mark_safe(item[-5:])
    request = context['request']
    model_admin = context['view'].model_admin
    field_name = model_admin.get_list_display(request)[index]
    if field_name == model_admin.get_list_display_add_buttons(request):
        add_action_buttons = True
        item = mark_safe(item[0:-5])
    context.update({
        'item': item,
        'add_action_buttons': add_action_buttons,
        'closing_tag': closing_tag,
    })
    return context
```

Going further I don't really understand how the `<td>` with the title are put in there nor what I can do to make it clickable or customise that template.

A screenshot to illustrate the UI section

[image: UI section]